# Почему значение элемента val() не записывается, если обратиться через id и записывается через class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form7

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным плагином [contact form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). 
Добавляю внутрь формы (она находится во всплывающем окне)

```
<input type="hidden" name="title-methodic" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden hide-title" id="hide-title">
```

и вот, что заметил: если обращаться к скрытому элементу через `id`, то значение в **val** не записывается, а если в `class`, то записывается.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    title = $(this).attr('data-title');
    $('.hide-title').val(title); //работает
    $('#hide-title').val(title); //не работает
});
```

Это почему так? Особенность `jquery`, `contact form 7`, всплывающего окна или какого другого функционала?

Comment: Проверьте нет ли дублирования на странице тегов с id="hide-title"

Comment: @Ofer да, понял. У меня несколько блоков вызывающих одинаковые формы. Вопрос закрыт